# Unity: build crashes when trying to copy `mesh`

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, mesh

This code works just fine in the Unity Editor:

```
MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
MeshFilter newFilter = visuals.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
newFilter.mesh = meshFilter.mesh; // [crashes here]
```

but crashes on the 3rd line when running as a Build.

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926177/unity-full-build-crashes-when-using-dynamic-meshes) that seems to be pretty similar but it doesn't provide any explanation as to why it does crash in the Build but not in the Editor. In my case I fixed it by using `sharedMesh` property instead of `mesh` but still have no idea about the crash reason. Any ideas?

---

**EDITED:**
The error text:

> Read from location 0000000000000218 caused an access violation.

the callstack ends with:

> 0x0000016FE7F431C4 (Assembly-CSharp)
>   .runtime_invoke_void__this___object() 0x00007FFC0663BBCB
>   (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_get_runtime_build_info 0x00007FFC065C2252
>   (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_perfcounters_init 0x00007FFC065CB25F
>   (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke 0x00007FFC07DBC6FD (UnityPlayer)
>   UnityMain 0x00007FFC07DB9441 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
>   0x00007FFC07D9E545 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain 0x00007FFC0748BACF
>   (UnityPlayer) UnityMain 0x00007FFC07EF2559 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
>   0x00007FFC07EF2172 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain 0x00007FFC07D10E99
>   (UnityPlayer) UnityMain 0x00007FFC07D0CC44 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
>   0x00007FFC07A8C157 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain 0x00007FFC07A8C225
>   (UnityPlayer) UnityMain 0x00007FFC07A8F92F (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
>   0x00007FFC073DF022 (UnityPlayer) PAL_Memory_Free 0x00007FFC073DD82A
>   (UnityPlayer) PAL_Memory_Free 0x00007FFC073E1F59 (UnityPlayer)
>   PAL_Memory_Free 0x00007FFC073E3BDB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain ERROR:
>   SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: 'Attempt to access invalid
>   address.' (Address: 00007FF6865A11F2) 0x00007FF6865A11F2 (ToyTanks)
>   (function-name not available) 0x00007FFC8B414034 (KERNEL32)
>   BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007FFC8BB63691 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

in the `error.log` file.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The error is similar to one from the linked question. I added some error info from the log. Actually, it doesn't make much sense for me and didn't even help to find the line which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshFilter-mesh.html):

> If a mesh is assigned to the mesh filter already, then first query of mesh property will create a duplicate of it, and this copy will be returned. Further queries of mesh property will return this duplicated mesh instance. Once mesh property is queried, link to the original shared mesh is lost and MeshFilter.sharedMesh property becomes an alias to mesh. If you want to avoid this automatic mesh duplication, use MeshFilter.sharedMesh instead.

For your first line of code, try this instead.

```
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
```

Comment: This wouldn't explain a crash though, would it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't explain why it works in the Editor and crashes in the Build. And there is nothing wrong with duplicating if I understand it correctly.

Comment: You are dereferncing the mesh for the GameObject this script is attached to. Does this script run more than once, by chance? @Sergey If it runs more than once, and the first object that gets a copy of the mesh has been destroyed, then you destroy the duplicated mesh, but not the alias that points to it.

Comment: @ErikOverflow it runs once per object. The original mesh filter is destroied `Destroy(meshFilter);` on the 4th line (which is not shown in the question).